# How to remove the title bar in pyglet, I'm making a splash intro

Tags: python, pyglet

Here's my codes:
I don't know how to remove the title bar in pyglet, I'm making a splash intro. Please help me Thank you!

```
ag_file = "splash.gif"

animation = pyglet.resource.animation(ag_file)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height)
win.set_location(325, 225)

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()
    sprite.draw()

def close(event):
    win.close()

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(close, 9.0)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out already!!! Here's my code:

```
ag_file = "splash.gif"

animation = pyglet.resource.animation(ag_file)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height, style = 'borderless')
win.set_location(325, 225)

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()
    sprite.draw()

def close(event):
    win.close()

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(close, 9.0)

pyglet.app.run()
```